# Prove that $\sum_i \vec r_i \times \vec uF_i = (\sum_i \vec r_iF_i) \times \vec u$

Tags: summation, vectors, vector-analysis, physics

Given an expression
$$\sum_i \vec r_i \times \vec uF_i $$
where $\vec r_i$ are position vectors from the origin, $\vec u$ is a constant unit vector and $F_i$ are constants, it is true that$$\sum_i \vec r_i \times \vec uF_i = (\sum_i \vec r_iF_i) \times \vec u.$$

How to prove that the above equation is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep it simple. You need just the following two properties of the cross product:

$$\vec{a}\times(k\vec{b})=(k\vec{a})\times\vec{b}\tag{1}$$

$$(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\times\vec{c}=\vec{a}\times\vec{c}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}\tag{2}$$

Both can be easily proved if you use the fact that the cross product of vectors $\vec{a}=a_x\vec{i}+a_y\vec{j}+a_z\vec{k}$ and  $\vec{b}=b_x\vec{i}+b_y\vec{j}+b_z\vec{k}$ is:

$$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=(a_yb_z-a_zb_y)\vec{i}+(a_zb_x-a_xb_z)\vec{j}+(a_xb_y-a_yb_x)\vec{k}$$

All this is explained in excellent detail on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition).

The proof is now simple:

$$\sum_i \vec r_i \times (F_i\vec u)=$$

$$\sum_i (F_i\vec r_i)  \times \vec u=\tag{(1) applied}$$

$$(\sum_i F_i\vec r_i)  \times \vec u\tag{(2) applied}$$

Answer (score 1):

I will use superscript for the index of the vector, so the subscript can be the element of a vector.
$$\left(\sum_{i} \vec{r}^i \times \vec{u}F^i\right)_j=$$
$$\sum_{i}\left(\vec{r}^i \times \vec{u}F^i\right)_j=$$
$$\sum_{i}\left(\sum_{k,l}\epsilon_{jkl} r^i_k u_lF^i\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k,l}\left(\sum_{i}\epsilon_{jkl} r^i_k u_lF^i\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k,l}\epsilon_{jkl}\left(\sum_{i} r^i_k F^i\right)u_l=$$
$$\sum_{k,l}\epsilon_{jkl}\left(\sum_{i} \vec{r}^i F^i\right)_ku_l=$$
$$\left(\left(\sum_{i} \vec{r}^i F^i\right)\times\vec{u}\right)_j$$
So we have that
$$\sum_{i} \vec{r}^i \times \vec{u}F^i=\left(\sum_{i} \vec{r}^i F^i\right)\times\vec{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an accepted answer, however there is a much more obvious proof. First note that $\vec{r}_i\times\vec{u}$ is just another vector, call it $\vec{q}_i$ so that
\begin{equation}
\sum_i  \vec{r}_i\times\vec{u} F_i = \sum_i \vec{q}_i F_i
\end{equation}
but because *scalar multiplication* of a vector by a scalar is *commutative*, this becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_i  \vec{r}_i\times\vec{u} F_i &=& \sum_i \vec{q}_i F_i  = \sum_i F_i \vec{q}_i \\
  &=& \sum_i F_i (\vec{r}_i\times\vec{u}) \\
  &=& \left( \sum_i F_i \vec{r}_I \right)\times\vec{u}
\end{eqnarray}
where we have factored the *constant* vector $\vec{u}$ outside of the sum in the last step.